# PHP code not working properly in windows 7 apache (localhost)

Tags: php, apache

I have an issue with a php code. 
This code is running smoothly in Linux but not in windows 7. Any suggestions?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
if(isset($_POST['confirmOrd'])){
        foreach($xml->xpath("orders/order[@id='".$_POST['confirmOrd']."']") as $change){
            $change->check =    date('d/m/Y');
        }
        $xml->asXML('data.xml');
}
```

In windows Apache server I get the error:

**Warning: main() [function.main]: Cannot assign to an array of nodes (duplicate subnodes or attr detected)**

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. You can suppress it by using error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING); in your program.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get any warnings on linux? Did you check the logs?

Comment: Not sure if I get any errors in linux but at least it works. In windows is not working at all

Comment: did have a chance to recheck my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$source = '<orders><order id="1"> <userid>Petros Petrou</userid> <date>04/01/2015</date> <check>0</check> <store>1</store> <product> <code>45887952</code> <quantity>1</quantity> </product> <product> <code>45887954</code> <quantity>1</quantity> </product> </order></orders>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($source);

$xpath = $xml->xpath("/orders/order[@id='1']");
if ($xpath!=false){ 
     foreach ( $xpath as $change){
            $change->check =    date('d/m/Y');
     }
}
var_dump($xpath);
var_dump($xml);
```

it works fine for me

I could be wrong. But just try :-)

Comment: could you provide `'data.xml'` data sample that you try to use?

Comment: `<order id="1">
  <userid>Petros Petrou</userid>
  <date>04/01/2015</date>
  <check>0</check>
  <store>1</store>
  <product>
   <code>45887952</code>
   <quantity>1</quantity>
  </product>
  <product>
   <code>45887954</code>
   <quantity>1</quantity>
  </product>
 </order>`

Comment: so where is your <orders> node?